# Array object grouping in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to convert below unformatted JSON format into formatted input. We need to find id's similar to parent id for different items inside array element of object and then need to push it into children to that id. Below is my code that needs to transform

### Input

```json
{
  "0": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "title": "House",
      "level": 0,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": null
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "title": "Red Roof",
      "level": 1,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "title": "Blue Roof",
      "level": 1,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 10
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "id": 17,
      "title": "Blue Windoww",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 12
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "title": "Door",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 13
    }
  ]
}
```

### Output

```json
[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "title": "House",
    "level": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 12,
        "title": "RedRoofff",
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 17,
            "title": "Blue Windoww",
            "level": 2,
            "children": [],
            "parent_id": 12
          }
        ],
        "parent_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "title": "Blue Roof",
        "level": 1,
        "children": [],
        "parent_id": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "title": "Wall",
        "level": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 16,
            "title": "Door",
            "level": 2,
            "children": [],
            "parent_id": 13
          }
        ],
        "parent_id": 10
      }
    ],
    "parent_id": null
  }
]
```

Please find the solution to above problem.

Answer (score 0):

first, we track the node with Id and then we update the children array like this.
(btw, your input have a missing node, 13)

```js
const input = {
  "0": [{
    "id": 10,
    "title": "House",
    "level": 0,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": null
  }, {
    "id": 13,
    "title": "Wall",
    "level": 0,
    "children": [],
    "parent_id": null
  }],
  "1": [{
      "id": 12,
      "title": "Red Roof",
      "level": 1,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 18,
      "title": "Blue Roof",
      "level": 1,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 10
    },
  ],
  "2": [{
      "id": 17,
      "title": "Blue Windoww",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 12
    },
    {
      "id": 16,
      "title": "Door",
      "level": 2,
      "children": [],
      "parent_id": 13
    },
  ]
};

const results = [];
const mapId2Node = Object.values(input).reduce((acc, vals) => {
  vals.forEach(val => {
    acc[val.id] = val;
    if (val.parent_id === null) {
      results.push(val);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

Object.values(input).forEach(vals => {
  vals.forEach(val => {
    if (val.parent_id !== null) {
      mapId2Node[val.parent_id].children.push(val);
    }
  });
});

conosle.log(results);
```

Comment: when I am trying to fetch dynamic input from <textarea> and trying to call this as function its not working in angular code

Comment: can you kindly be precise about what do not work? We are here to help, and you need to provide information or code on what is/are not working.